# Pass clean URL test with IIS and Ionic rewrite module

Tags: 6, .htaccess

The IT department moved my drupal 6 site to a new server. It is IIS7 server with ISAPI Rewrite Module (Ionic).

My main problem is that the clean URLs do not work. I have set this up thousants of times on Apache machines, but IIS is new to me, and with Ionic.

Things I have tried googling around and looking at the drupal man page for cleanURLs:

Added this to .htaccess:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /antor/  #both leaving this line our, and tried with #
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But does IIS even look at htaccess? So I also created a web.config file with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Drupal clean URLs" enabled="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />    
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="/favicon.ico$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?q={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</configuration>
```

Then I got: internal server error 500.

But perhaps the rewrite module does look at htaccess? I am puzzled...

Comment: I can't answer this, but I would take the web.config from Drupal 7, and adapt it for Drupal 6.  The only real change that I can think of would to change how the punt to index.php works.  Drupal 7 just takes the request as-is.  Drupal 6 does the QSA.  You may also need to remove some rules.

Comment: I have used this web.config file, but it gives an 500 server error. Any idea why?

Comment: Even if I just add a web.config file with: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration></configuration> I get the 500 error, Perhaps I can just use htaccess?

Comment: In the end, my webserver changed to the internal rewrite module of IIS and the web.config worked.